# brake pedal staying down. Then ok after a few days being stood

Tags: brakes, mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes C200 and the other day the brake pedal stayed down while I was driving. It did come back up a little as I carried on home. I haven't driven the car for a day or so. then this morning I was going to take the car to a garage to look at it and the brakes were OK. then just as I pulled back in my drive the brakes felt a bit wrong again, but not with the pedal staying down. could i need new pads. or is this the servo or master cylinder. I would like to be able to find a diagram of the system so I know what hose is going to the servo and others. If any one has one please post it up.

Comment: What year is your car?